# remove table row after item deleted in database using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a delete button that deletes an entry in the database. I would like to hide the table row of that entry after the deletion but can't find a way to hide the `tr`.

My code is:

```
 $(document).on('click' , 'a.delete-dialog', function(){
    var id_hired_staff = $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-id_hired_staff');
  $("#dialog-confirm").data('del-id_hired_staff', id_hired_staff).dialog('open');
  return false;
});

var buttonsOpts = {}
buttonsOpts[Settings.fire_staff] = function() {
  var id_hired_staff = $(this).data('del-id_hired_staff');
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/path/fire_staff",
    data: "id_hired_staff="+id_hired_staff,
    success: function(result){
      $("tr").find("[data-id_hired_staff='" + id_hired_staff + "']").hide(); // This is what I've tried
   }
  });
$(this).dialog('close');
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `$("table").children("tr[data-id_hired_staff='" + id_hired_staff + "']").hide();` (`"table"` can be any other selector of course). You should also add `var id_hired_staff;` outside the click callback function, and inside it just do `id_hired_staff = $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-id_hired_staff');` so the variable will be available outside the function scope

Comment: Sorry I'm not an expert. I tried what you suggested, with `children` but it still doesn't remove the line. Do you mean I need to add `id_hired_staff = $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-id_hired_staff');` inside the `success: function(result){` and keep `var id_hired_staff = $(this).data('del-id_hired_staff');` just inside `buttonsOpts[Settings.fire_staff] = function() {`? I tried that too

Comment: I put my comment as an answer, please try it and let me know how it went

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will write my comment as an answer:

```
 var id_hired_staff;
 $(document).on('click' , 'a.delete-dialog', function(){
    id_hired_staff = $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-id_hired_staff');
  $("#dialog-confirm").data('del-id_hired_staff', id_hired_staff).dialog('open');
  return false;
});

var buttonsOpts = {}
buttonsOpts[Settings.fire_staff] = function() {
  var id_hired_staff = $(this).data('del-id_hired_staff');
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/path/fire_staff",
    data: "id_hired_staff="+id_hired_staff,
    success: function(result){
      $("table").find("tr[data-id_hired_staff='" + id_hired_staff + "']").hide(); // This is what I've tried
   }
  });
$(this).dialog('close');
}
```

I put `id_hired_staff` as a global variable so it will be available outside the `click` callback function scope. and changed the selector to something I believe will work

Comment: works like a charm with `find`, not with `children`. Thanks!

Comment: @remyremy Thanks - And it probably didn't work with `children` because when used - it only searching a single level down the DOM, so if the table has `<tbody>` then it won't work (while `find` can travel multiple levels down the DOM)

Comment: Correct, I have a `<tbody`, now I understand!